# Navigate Programmatically Ionic-React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router

I'm working with React and Ionic, after a form submission, I want to navigate programmatically to the next route,

When I do:

```
const { navigate } = useContext(NavContext);
// After Async call....
navigate("/", "forward", "pop").
```

it works.

While I was going through ionic-react documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#navigation I saw that they used `history` to navigate programmatically, and it says `note: history is a prop`.

I tried the above statement, and I get: `Property 'history' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.`

an explanation is needed.

App.tsx

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
     <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true} />
     <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
     <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

Comment: use history.push()

Comment: if i take history as prop, it gives the above error, if i import history from react-router-dom, i think it should work

Comment: can you plz wrap the full code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample code for conditionally navigate.In case any problem let me know

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Form = () => {
const history = useHistory();

return(
<div>
if(condition){
history.push("/example")
}

</div>
)}
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct sir... if you take history as a prop like ionic said, you will get errors

Comment: ok, how is your issue is it solved or not?

Comment: please accept my answer it will increase my reputation